# Problems setting up gettext

Tags: php, translation, gettext, multilingual

I am trying to get a simple gettext working but I am just getting the english version back. I have never done any multi-language support so this is very new for me. I am working with php version 5.5.28 on a windows test server however production will be on a ubuntu server. Here is the simple php code i am using. The GET['lang'] = 'es_ES' for this test.

```
$language = $_GET['lang'];
echo $language . '<br>';
putenv( "LANG=$language" );
setlocale( LC_ALL, $language );

$domain = 'messages';
echo CORE_PATH . "locale";
echo '<br>';
bindtextdomain( $domain, CORE_PATH . "locale" );
textdomain( $domain );

echo gettext( "A string to be translated would go here" );
echo '<br>';
echo _( 'test' );
echo '<br>';
```

Here is the locale directory

```
├───en_US
│   └───LC_MESSAGES
└───es_ES
    └───LC_MESSAGES
        ├───messages.po
        └───messages.mo
```

here is the message.po if it helps

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: csc-pathways\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2017-07-10 11:07-0700\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2017-07-10 11:08-0700\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"Language: es\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 2.0.2\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: ../../../pages\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: UTF-8\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: .\n"

#: test.php:20
msgid "A string to be translated would go here"
msgstr "Una cadena a traducir iría aquí"

#: test.php:22
msgid "test"
msgstr "prueba"
```